# Using a variable from bootstrap.groovy file in config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I an initializing as variable in bootstrap.groovy file like this

```
def logLocation = Tunable.findByTunaTag("LogLocation")
```

Here `Tunable` is a domain class.

I want to use this variable `logLocation` in config.groovy file.How do i achieve this? .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is executed after the Config is read.  But you can change the config from the bootstrap:

```
`grailsApplication.config.logLocation = ...`
```

Comment: Didn't work out for me. In config.groovy i added
`def log4jFileName = logLocation + "TNMRest.log"`
And in bootstrap :
`grailsApplication.config.logLocation = "D:\\amit\\"`

Comment: as i said, _config_ is handled **before** _bootstrap_. you would have to use your code the other way around. but since your var there is `def log4j...` i fear the problem goes way deeper...

Comment: Can i do something like this 
`def logLocation = Tunable.findByTunaTag("LogLocation")`
in config.groovy file  ??

Comment: AFAIR no, since config is one of the very first things